Can't run this app by multiple users concurrently in shinyapps.io and problem with chromote package
I have created a shiny app to scrape the "google title" from the google page ("https://google.com") using the chromote package. The app works fine on the desktop. However, once it is hosted on a shinyapps.io server, two users cannot use it concurrently. The code for the app is in below,
---------------------- Code (findGoogleTitle.R) -------------------------------
library(shiny)
library(curl)
library(chromote)
library(pagedown)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  driver <- ChromoteSession$new()
  driver$Page$navigate("https://google.com") # open Google page
  Sys.sleep(7)
  output$result <- renderText(
    driver$Runtime$evaluate(
      'document.querySelector("title").innerText'
    )$result$value
  ) # scrape Google title
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

---------------------- End --------------------------------
Output:

Click on: https://sale4cast.shinyapps.io/findGoogleTitle/
Wait 5 seconds.
Get the google title "Google"Question: How can two users access the app concurrently via shinyapps.io?.

Best Regards,
SaleForecast

In order for multiple users to be able to use your app concurrently, you will need to containerize your app with docker. Hugging Face makes this process simple. Take a look at this blog post: https://ifeanyidiaye.medium.com/how-to-deploy-an-r-shiny-app-as-a-hugging-face-space-486532b0e58a
